# GNUPLOT: How to annotate curves with columhead

Tags: gnuplot

I am using

```
plot for [i=0:1] "DiffT" every:::i::i w l lw 2 title columnhead
```

to plot 2 curves that are stored in a single data file with a blank line separating them. At the beginning of each curve data I include data that I want as title for the curve. However this only works for the first curve.

the data file is:

```
0.1                 # title for the first curve
3 1.68791e-03 
4 8.99050e-05
5 4.94916e-06 

0.2                # title for the second curve
6 2.44474e-07 
7 1.19909e-08 
8 1.39325e-09
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two empty lines as separators, `index` to select the data set and then `columnhead` works:

`DiffT` is:

```
0.1                 # title for the first curve
3 1.68791e-03 
4 8.99050e-05
5 4.94916e-06 


0.2                # title for the second curve
6 2.44474e-07 
7 1.19909e-08 
8 1.39325e-09
```

And plot with

```
plot for [i=0:1] "DiffT" index i w l lw 2 title columnhead(1)
```